# Django from doesn't get processed. HTTP 405 error raises

Tags: python, django

I am trying to process a `post` form, but I can't manage. I have prepared the form, gave the action link, set the method to post, but when I hit the submit button, nothing happens, not even an error page isn't shown by django despite my debug option is `True`.

Here is the form code in my template file:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'articles:stepprocess' 0 %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <p><label for="title">Title:</label>
                        <input name="title" id="title" type="text"/></p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="dif">Difficulty</label>
                        <select name="dif" id="dif">
                            {% if difficulties %}
                                {% for difficulty in difficulties %}
                                    <option value="{{ difficulty.pk }}">{{ difficulty }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </select>
                    </p>

                    <p><label for="article">Content:</label>
                        <textarea cols="37" rows="11" name="article" id="article"></textarea></p>

                    <p><input name="send" style="margin-left: 150px;" class="formbutton" value="Send"
                              type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

My `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^new/(?P<step>[0-9]+)/$', NewArticle.as_view(), name="newarticle_continue"),
    url(r'^new/', NewArticle.as_view(), name="newarticle"),
    url(r'^new/process/(?P<step>[0-9]+)/$', FormManager.as_view(), name='stepprocess')
    #url(r'^show/(?P<article>[0-9]+)/$'),
]
```

And lastly, my views.py file:

```
#required imports...

class FormManager(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(kwargs['step'])
```

When I hit the submit button, it gives me HTTP 405 error. I can see this error in python console but nothing shows in browser. Just blank white screen.

This was actually to test if view works properly. My final purpose is that I would like to access the post variables and redirect the page. However, `HttpResponseRedirect` also doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP 405 error means "method not allowed"

In your case you are POSTing... the view looks like it should accept POST requests though.

The problem is your urls.py is wrong, the url you POSTed to is intercepted by the `NewArticle` view instead, which I guess only accepts GETs.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^new/process/(?P<step>[0-9]+)/$', FormManager.as_view(), name='stepprocess')
    url(r'^new/(?P<step>[0-9]+)/$', NewArticle.as_view(), name="newarticle_continue"),
    url(r'^new/', NewArticle.as_view(), name="newarticle"),
    #url(r'^show/(?P<article>[0-9]+)/$'),
]
```

Django looks at the urls in the urlconf *in the order they are defined* and will dispatch your request to the *first one that matches*.

Above I have modified the order, alternatively you could just add the `$` to end of url:

```
url(r'^new/$', NewArticle.as_view(), name="newarticle"),
```

this will prevent it matching any `new/*` url paths.